# Error: The Azure PowerShell context has not been properly initialized. Please import the module and try again

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-storage, azure-powershell

I have a azure powershell function app. The job of this function app is to generate azure storage account SAS token

I am using the following command to generate the token

```
$StartTime = Get-Date
$EndTime = $StartTime.AddMinutes(50.0)
$token = Get-AzStorageAccount -Name "<storage-account-name>" -ResourceGroupName "<resource-group-name>" | New-AzStorageContainerSASToken  -Container <container-name> -Permission rdwl -StartTime $StartTime -ExpiryTime $EndTime
```

The code gave the valid sas token for some days. But since some time its throwing error

> The Azure PowerShell context has not been properly initialized.  Please import the module and try again

I saw a few questions mentioning "'`session` has not been properly initialized'" and nowhere mention for context.

I need help in resolving this issue

Comment: Did you make sure to import the module after installing it? Additionally, sometimes after installing a module a simple reboot of your machine should help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely caused by https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-powershell-worker/issues/554. The recently released Az.Accounts 2.1.* introduced this regression. Until this is fixed in the modules, the temporary workaround is to roll back to Az.Accounts 1.9.5 by using these instructions: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-powershell-worker/issues/552#issue-732797653. Please note that this step is critically important:

```
Import-Module Az.Accounts -RequiredVersion '1.9.5'
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `"the context has not been properly initialized"` is different with `"the session has not been properly initialized"`. Maybe the module had been lost after run several days.

After checking the [documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-powershell?tabs=portal#use-powershell-modules-by-configuring-an-entrypoint) about using PowerShell modules, my suggestion is use `Save-Module` before publishing your Function. Consider deploying your function app to an **App Service plan** set to **always on** or to a **Premium plan**.

A more complex solution may also work is [configure the context manually](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/context-persistence?view=azps-5.0.0#create-a-new-azure-context-from-subscription-information).

Comment: I tried using Save-Module and saved the modules Az.Account and Az.Storage into the modules and imported the same into the run file. This seems to be working absolutely fine in local.

While deploying I used the path `D:\home\site\wwwroot` as the prefix as that is the location where azure functions are deployed. But this hasn't solved the error of `"the context has not been properly initialized"`.

Comment: While debugging I tried fetching context using `Get-AzContext` command. This too woked in local while in deployed version it says command not recognised